# How to find overlapping hours of a timerange and a date range?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, timespan

I have a time range `11:00 PM` to `5:00 AM`. **(night hours range)**

I have date range for eg.,
`2014-04-01 00:00:00` to  `2014-04-02 23:59:59`

Now I need to calculate how many **night hours** are present in the given date range.

For the above example it should return **11 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds**

**Explanation:**

`2014-04-01 00:00 AM` to `2014-04-01 5:00 AM` = 5 hours

`2014-04-01 11:00 PM` to `2014-04-02 5:00 AM` = 6 hours

`2014-04-02 11:00 PM` to `2014-04-02 11:59:59 PM` = 0 hour 59 minutes 59 seconds

one second approximation is okay.

Comment: where did you stucked?

Comment: Will the dates always be one day apart? What should the answer be for `2014-04-02 23:00` and `2014-04-10 07:00`

Answer (score 2):

If these are strings, you need to parse them to [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then get difference them with [`-`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wch5w409.aspx) operator. This gets you a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I see your strings have different formats. You need to parse them matched format one by one.

After that, you can use [`TimeSpan` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
string s = "2014-04-01 00:00 AM";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                               "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s1 = "2014-04-01 5:00 AM";
var date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(s1,
                                "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm tt",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


TimeSpan ts = date1 - date;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"{0} hours {1} minutes {2} seconds",
                                  ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
```

Output will be;

```
5 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
```

If they are already `DateTime`, just use `-` operator and use [`.Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`.Minutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`.Seconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of `TimeSpan` structure.

There is a project called [Calculating Business Hours](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19559/Calculating-Business-Hours) which is calculate business hours between two DateTime. You can implement your own night shift hours based this project.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It's not time span. The question is slightly different. I need to calculate how many **night shift hours** are present in the given date range.

Comment: My English is not perfect but what do you mean by _night shift hours_ exactly? Is there any time range for shifting?

Comment: Yes it's a time range. 11:00 PM to 5:00 AM ( when night shift workers work in the factory). It's basically night hours. Edited the question details for clarity.

Comment: @Sathish There is a project called [Calculating Business Hours](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19559/Calculating-Business-Hours) which is calculate business hours between two DateTime. You can implement your own night shift hours based this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **CalendarPeriodCollector** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void NightHours()
{
    CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
    filter.CollectingHours.Add( new HourRange( 0, 5 ) ); // working hours
    filter.CollectingHours.Add( new HourRange( 23, 24 ) ); // working hours

    CalendarTimeRange testPeriod =
       new CalendarTimeRange( new DateTime( 2014, 4, 1 ), 
       new DateTime( 2014, 4, 3 ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "Calendar period collector of period: " + testPeriod );

    CalendarPeriodCollector collector =
                    new CalendarPeriodCollector( filter, testPeriod );
    collector.CollectHours();
    Console.WriteLine( "Duration: " + new DateDiff( collector.Periods.TotalDuration ) );
} // NightHours
```